# Two jQuery scripts are not working simultaneously on IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery for 2 features:

1. Drop down menu.
2. Drag and drop panels.

**The Problem**:

Drop down menu use a jQuery as a fix for Internet Explorer 7 later...

When I call jQuery fix for Internet Explorer 7 later in the head of the page after the drag and drop panels jQuery, drop down panels jQuery works fine, but the drag and drop panels stop working.

And when I call Internet Explorer 7 later fix jQuery before the drag and drop panels, then the panels work fine but the drop down doesn't works...

Its happening only in Internet Explorer 6.
CHECK IN IE6
Buttons Working, but Panels Not Working
http://global.redhatsalesteam.com/buttons_working/

Panels Working, But Buttons Not Working
http://global.redhatsalesteam.com/drags_working/

Comment: Nope, not enough details. You need to post the code here please.

Comment: You shouldn't use two versions of jQuery on the same page, if that's what you mean. It's way better (although sometimes hard) to fix one of the components to work with the other's version.

Comment: I vote we blame IE and close the topic! Joke. Seriously now, post some code, especially the fix that's giving some issues.

Comment: ok, i am uploading.. so you can have all the details

Comment: @Pekka seeing the tags and the way it's explained, I believe Pal is using two jQuery /plugins/ or scripts, or anything else a normal human can't understand from this awkward explaination :-)

Comment: IE6 is downright prehistoric at this point.  Have you considered detecting IE6 and instructing the user to upgrade to a modern version of IE before letting them use your page?

Comment: Depends on your audience and stats... 1% of 1 000 000 is 10 000 users

Comment: Hai @aroth I can't upgrade my IE6 at work, thx for the annoying message and making me feel stupid, im leaving your website now

Comment: CHECK IN IE6
Buttons Working, but Panels Not Working
http://global.redhatsalesteam.com/buttons_working/

Panels Working, But Buttons Not Working
http://global.redhatsalesteam.com/drags_working/

Comment: Although I feel your pain @Madmartigan you should seriously approach your IS/IT department and ask when you can get an updated, secure web browser.  Support for IE6 is dropping fast... is "only just" supported by Microsoft (on specific flavors of XP).  IE6 is 10 years old. Please let it out to pasture.

Comment: @ Capsule... i know i had explaned in little awkward way... but dont comment unnecessarily

Comment: @Madmartigan Then you need to fire and replace your IT department.  There's no excuse for such laziness when it comes to corporate network maintenance.

Comment: @scunliffe, just playing Devil's advocate. Browser upgrade messages are never the solution to fixing problems in IE, it's a cop out.

Comment: Any1 have Solution... :S

Comment: pal can you post the javascript, you may just not need to call the fix twice.

Comment: @Capsule 1% is 1% whether that's 1million or 10 users. Its normalized. Now if your targeting a 25% or 30% audience then yeah go and bother.

Comment: @pal singh: I can't get the panels working with either link in IE6 or IE7... You're missing a closing tag on one of the last `<li>`s too. ALways validate first before attempting to debug IE!

Comment: it must be a mistake in copy paste

Answer (score 2):

http://www.bringdownie6.com/

This. This is what you need to look at.

Comment: I also support that... but you should pass that to my company owner or companies clients.. :P

Comment: Errr there's nothing you can do to "bring down" IE. You just have to be patient. If you truly want to bash IE users, just let your site look like garbage in it. Or did you mean to link [here](http://saveie6.com/)?  :)

Comment: LOL, save IE6...kill that guy who had made that website

Comment: @Calum, my downvote. read OPs comment again. He's most likely doing this job for someone else. That stuff is ok for your personal blog or whatever but not paid jobs, especially if you were paid to get the site running on IE6/7. That being said, I'm stepping out of this doomed convo.

Answer (score 1):

Your expecting open source jQuery 3rd party plugins to be a) well-written, b) isolated and thoroughly unit tested on IE6 and c) not conflict with any other jQuery plugin.

These aims are just not achievable.

The solution is to write the functionality from scratch yourself. If you want IE6 support you need to do hand tailoring and yes that will increase your project time from 10 minutes of banging jQuery plugins together to a couple of days of writing maintainable and sustainable IE6 code.

Your also using jQuery 1.3.2 and jQuery UI 1.7, how do you expect to fully support IE6 if you don't upgrade your versions of jQuery to the latest one which have numerous bug fixes for IE6 in them.

Comment: FWIW (probably nothing) I'm on the jquery UI site in IE6 now and everything works fine.

Comment: @Madmartigan but they are running the latest version jQuery UI (1.8.11). Have you tried running the QUnit tests for jQuery UI 1.7.2.custom and the QUnit tests for jQuery 1.3.2 on IE6 ?

Comment: @palsingh debug jQuery UI and change your `jQuery UI.1.7.2.custom` file to not have any bugs in IE6. Start with running the QUnit tests in IE6. Add some QUnit tests for running drag&drop and drop down menus together. Then make the QUnit tests pass.

Comment: @Raynos I was agreeing with you (my upvote) and disagreeing with everyone else at the same time, and letting OP know that it's not hopeless, keep working at it.

Comment: @Madmartigan using outdated jQuery scripts and expecting them to work in IE6 out of the box is asking a bit much imho

Comment: @ Raynos... can you explain a little more...i am a rookie

Answer (score 0):

Finally Got the Solution :D
Simply put this between your source jquery

var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();

FOR EXAMPLE

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery_1.3.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();

</script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery_1.2.js'></script>
```

Comment: Your using two versions of jQuery ? _WHY_ Please upgrade _all_ your jQuery to 1.4+ or at least 1.3.2. This is just a _dirty_ hack to get a fix _now_ and the maintainer of your code will hate you.

Comment: how to upgrade... i dont know that... please if you can help me with that

Comment: download jQuery version 1.5.2 from http://www.jquery.com/ and change all `<script src="js/jquery_x.x.js">` to `<script src="js/jquery_1.5.2.js">`. Then run your tests and fix any bugs that are caused by old scripts relying on old versions of jquery (1.3 and 1.2)